# How can I tell if the input method picker is open or closed?

Tags: android, android-input-method, android-contextmenu

My app opens the input method picker (the menu where you choose a keyboard) with `InputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker()`. My app doesn't actually create the picker (it's created by InputMethodManager) but I know it's a `ContextMenu` and its id is `R.id.switchInputMethod`.

[image]

The picker is part of a multi-step wizard so I need to know when the picker closes so my app can proceed to the next step. Right now I'm checking in a background thread if the default keyboard changed, **but that doesn't help if the user selects the same keyboard or presses back.**

So I need a way to tell when the picker closes (or some other clever way to know when to proceed).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such mechanism for check `InputMethodPicker` is open or not.

But you can check it via another way like as using `hasWindowFocus()` method for check has focus of your root layout.

Below is sample code:

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Picker" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**DemoappActivity.class**

```
public class DemoappActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    Button btn1 , btn2;
    InputMethodManager imeManager;

    LinearLayout mLayoutRoot;
    TimerTask timertask;
    Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLayoutRoot = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPicker);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showInputMethodPicker();
            }
        });
        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
        checkMyWindowHasFocus();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        timer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void checkMyWindowHasFocus()
    {
        timertask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("has window focus..."+mLayoutRoot.hasWindowFocus());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has focus "+mLayoutRoot.hasWindowFocus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timertask, 500, 5000);

    }

    private void showInputMethodPicker() {

        if (imeManager != null) {
            imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you mean to say if your Root Layout isn't having focus then it means `InputMethodPicker` is opened? then what about other cases which takes root layout focus away?

Comment: This works quite well, except I think Activity.onWindowFocusChanged() is better than a background thread. I'm still testing the code and will reply again soon. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I never would have thought to check window focus. Your solution works great (although I prefer using onWindowFocusChanged()).

Answer (score 17):

Here is a small trick. Please do test it and let us know if it works.

All you have to do is make your activity extend this InputMethodActivity. When you need the user to pick input method, call **pickInput()**, and **onInputMethodPicked()** will be called when the user is done.

```
package mobi.sherif.inputchangecheck;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public abstract class InputMethodActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    protected abstract void onInputMethodPicked();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mState = NONE;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(mState == PICKING) {
            mState = CHOSEN;
        }
        else if(mState == CHOSEN) {
            onInputMethodPicked();

        }
    }

    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int PICKING = 1;
    private static final int CHOSEN = 2;
    private int mState;
    protected final void pickInput() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showInputMethodPicker();
        mState = PICKING;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you post the call to onInputMethodPicked() instead of calling it directly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is correct and I prefer using onWindowFocusChanged(), but I awarded the bounty to CapDroid since he answered first with essentially the same answer as yours (check window focus).

Comment: For me, this only sort of worked. I'm `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);` to determine if my keyboard was selected, however, I don't think the value is set when `onInputMethodPicked` is called. I ended up adding a Handler to the class, and `postDelaying` by 300ms the implementation just so the value returned could settle. Its hacky, but it worked.

Comment: Please pardon me, but how/where do I call `pickInput()`? I tried to assign it to a button's onclick listener by doing `pickInput();`, but it says that the method cannot be resolved.

Comment: @ErlendK.H.You must extend this activity or just copy and paste all the methods to your own activity.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can know by using buildin function:

```
 @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            isMyInputMethodEnabled();// write what ever you want to do after default keyboard selected
        }


  public void isMyInputMethodEnabled() {
        String imId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
        if (imId.contains(getPackageName())) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Main_uk.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```