# Detect if Input Method has been selected

Tags: android, android-input-method

In my application I need to make the user choose an input method. Once it's selected I should perform some task. How is detected that the user actually chooses an `InputMethod`?

This is the code used to show the `InputMethod` list.

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) mw.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if (imeManager != null) {
    imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(mw.getApplicationContext(), "IME ERROR",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: "In my application I need to make the user choose an input method" -- why?

Comment: @CommonsWare because it handles behavior of a specific input device.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot catch the input method which user picks in `InputMethodPicker`.

However, you can check it after user picks it, using `BroadcastReceiver`.
When IME changes, `Intent.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED` will be broadcasted.

```
public class InputMethodChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED)) {
            .....
            /* You can check the package name of current IME here.*/
        }
    }
}
```

Then, register it.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thank you, it's enough for what I need!

Comment: Unfortunately the context.packageName always just returns your own package name, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Figured it out. Here's how to get the selected IME: 

`Settings.Secure.getString(ctx?.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD)`

Answer (score 7):

Well, even though you accepted the answer, there is a way to check if user selects your keyboard as a default:

```
public static boolean isThisKeyboardSetAsDefaultIME(Context context) {
    final String defaultIME = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
    return isThisKeyboardSetAsDefaultIME(defaultIME, context.getPackageName());
}

public static boolean isThisKeyboardSetAsDefaultIME(String defaultIME, String myPackageName) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultIME))
        return false;

    ComponentName defaultInputMethod = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(defaultIME);
    if (defaultInputMethod.getPackageName().equals(myPackageName)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can combine this code with code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981782/how-can-i-tell-if-the-input-method-picker-is-open-or-closed) and once user selects keyboard from *InputMethodPicker* check if your keyboard is a default (meaning that user selected it).

If you have more questions about implementing a keyboard, check this [project](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i am doing this way to detect if my ime is selected or enabled

for checking isSelected

```
 public static boolean isThisKeyboardSelected(Context context) {
        final String defaultIME = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultIME))
            return false;
        ComponentName defaultInputMethod = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(defaultIME);
//        return defaultInputMethod.getPackageName().equals(myPackageName);
        return defaultIME.contains("your package Name here");

    }



     public static boolean isThisKeyboardSetAsDefaultIME(Context context) {
        final String defaultIME = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_INPUT_METHODS);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(defaultIME))
            return false;
        ComponentName defaultInputMethod = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(defaultIME);
//        return defaultInputMethod.getPackageName().equals(myPackageName);
        return defaultIME.contains("your package name);

    }
```