# Call a non-static method inside an abstract class from a static method

Tags: java, android, methods, static, abstract-class

I'm trying to detect when the input method picker called by `InputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker()` is closed or changed. I found a possible solution proposed by Sherif elKhatib in another question: [How can I tell if the input method picker is open or closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981782/how-can-i-tell-if-the-input-method-picker-is-open-or-closed). His answer suggests that the OP should use an abstract non-static class. However, I don't know how to call a method from the abstract class in a static method. I thought I'd open a separate question for it here because the original question is already old and inactive.

Here is the solution introduced by Sherif:

```
public abstract class InputMethodActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    protected abstract void onInputMethodPicked();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mState = NONE;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(mState == PICKING) {
            mState = CHOSEN;
        }
        else if(mState == CHOSEN) {
            onInputMethodPicked();
        }
    }

    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int PICKING = 1;
    private static final int CHOSEN = 2;
    private int mState;
    protected final void pickInput() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showInputMethodPicker();
        mState = PICKING;
    }
}
```

The method I'd like to call is `pickInput()` in order to get a response from `onInputMethodPicked()`.

However, simply called `pickInput();` from a static method doesn't work, and won't even find it.

Furthermore, `InputMethodActivity.pickInput();` gives the error "*Non-static method 'pickInput()' cannot be referenced from a static context*".

Next, I tried to instantiate it, but I found out that abstracts cannot be instantiated: `InputMethodActivity instant = new InputMethodActivity();` gives the error "*'InputMethodActivity' is abstract; cannot be instantiated*".

After further reading, I tried to create an anomynous class: `InputMethodActivity anonym = new InputMethodActivity() {};`, but this gives the error "Class '*Anonymous class derived from InputMethodActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onInputMethodPicked()' in 'InputMethodActivity'*". I thought both of them were already declared abstract, so I'm nearing the end of my ropes here.

**Problem:**

Basically, I would like to know if it's possible to run `pickInput()` in a static method, such as a `public void onClick_TextView(View v){}`, and how it can be achieved.

Comment: please post the code of your class where you want to call this method

Comment: and make sure you inherit from this abstract activity

Comment: @Amrnoid I added the code inside `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {}`. Could you please explain how to inherit from the abstract activity? Sorry, my java knowledge is somewhat limited.

Comment: see my answer @Erlend K.H.

Answer (score 0):

abstract class you can only inherit it and write different implemnetaion for abstract method like `onInputMethodPicked` method in different derived classes 
and by inheritance you can use any method from `InputMethodActivity`  (parent class) in 
`MainActivity` (child class) like `pickInput` method

```
   public class MainActivity extends InputMethodActivity implements     View.OnTouchListener {
     @Override
     protected  void onInputMethodPicked(){
     // your implemetion after pick 
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
     pickInput();
   }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Amrnoid, but if I change `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {}` to `public class MainActivity extends InputMethodActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {}`, I get a lot of new errors since other parts of the code require `AppCompatActivity`. However, I think we are close to making it work. Is there a way to extend `MainActivity` to both `AppCompatActivity` and `InputMethodActivity`?

Comment: if A class inherit from B class and B class inherit from C,  C class is parent of A class by default   then AppCompatActivity  is parent class of MainActivity

Comment: java doesn’t provide support for multiple inheritance in classes so you can't extend MainActivity to both AppCompatActivity and InputMethodActivity