# Android Keyboard/IME switched listener

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, inputmethodmanager

I have developed a custom keyboard. I ask the user to switch to it using         `inputMethodManager.showInputMethodPicker()`.

How can i implement a listener that gets invoked when the user actually changes the keyboard/ime while using my application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069079/5791681